# How to make an offline java application available online?

Tags: java, web-applications

I have developed an offline java application and i would like to host it online in internet. I am not sure how to adapt my code as an webapplication. How to adapt html css to my code? (as i already have GUI). thanks.

Not able to find the right example or how tos on internet

Comment: Downvoting since the question is lacking information and is way too broad.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some cloud services to run your application, for example you can use AWS (aws.amazon.com/cloud‎).

Steps you need to perform:

- register your account there;
- add credit card (it's gonna take like a few dollars from that);
- install application container (like tomcat);
- deploy your application to tomcat server (for example);
- run tomcat (for example).

That's all, enjoy your application online.